# Can acquire and write to swap chain image be synchronized without a semaphore or fence?

Tags: vulkan

Typically, a `VkRenderPass` that uses a swap chain image waits for a semaphore from `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` before executing `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`. The same `VkRenderPass` also defines a subpass dependency to transition the image at the beginning of the same pipeline stage:

```
    VkSubpassDependency dependency = {
    .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    .dstSubpass = 0,
    // .srcStageMask needs to be a part of pWaitDstStageMask in the WSI semaphore.
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .srcAccessMask = 0,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    .dependencyFlags = 0};

//source: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#combined-graphicspresent-queue
```

According to Vulkan standard:

> 7: Subpass dependencies describe **execution** and memory dependencies between subpasses.

So doesn't this subpass dependency alone enforce that the `VkRenderPass` color output happens after the presentation engine `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`? What does the semaphore from `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` wait for, that the dependency does not?

I couldn't test absence of the semaphore effectively. On my Mesa Linux, render succeeds even without both sync methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution dependencies establish dependencies between two scopes: a source scope and a destination scope. Source external subpass dependencies define these as follows:

> If `srcSubpass` is equal to `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, the first synchronization scope includes commands that occur earlier in submission order than the `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` used to begin the render pass instance.

Note the key phrase "earlier *in submission order*". [Submission order](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap6.html#synchronization-submission-order) is defined on the basis of commands being submitted to a queue.

As you may have noticed, `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` does not take a queue as a parameter. Its name also does not start with "Cmd". These are clues that the operation is not submitted to any queue; it is a *device*-level operation.

Since acquiring an image is not part of any queue's "submission order", it cannot (unless other synchronization is employed) be part of the "first synchronization scope" of the external subpass dependency. Therefore, such a dependency has no effect on acquire operations.

So if you need an execution dependency on the use of an image you have acquired, it must be through a semaphore or fence.

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan 7.1.

> If srcSubpass is equal to VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, the first synchronization scope includes **commands** that occur earlier in **submission** **order** than the vkCmdBeginRenderPass used to begin the render pass instance.

`vkAcquireNextImageKHR` is not in the first synchronization scope of the subpass dependency, because it's not a command submitted to a queue.

The semaphore synchronizes the stages. As the image transition happens at the beginning of the color output stage, it comes after the semaphore is signaled. As both wait for the `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, operations from this stage before the semaphore are chained to the transition dependencies. Only by this chain the subpass dependency can know when the image was acquired to perform the transition. The writes in the output stage actually depend on the transition then, not directly on the semaphore.